# What design pattern should I use for using Cloudstorage like S3 and/or Azure Blob?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, amazon-web-services, design-patterns

I'm building up an emailing system which retrieves incoming email with attachments and also responds to emails; this requires saving and storing attachments into Azure blob and/or AWS S3 storage...

I have two controllers, `CommentsController` and `TicketsController`; both controllers need to use Azure API or AWS Storage to store and retrieve files.

This is my current code

```
Class CommentsController extends Controller {

     $accountKey2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     $accountName1 = "xxxxxxxx";
     $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" . $accountName1 . ";AccountKey=" . $accountKey2;
     $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);


}
```

As you can see above i will need to use the azure **$blobRestProxy** on every controller and whenever i need to upload files.

What is a good design pattern to use in this scenario?

I'm thinking a repository pattern which I will inject the azure interface into the controllers.

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i see, i will update my question, thank you for the reminder

Comment: You are Welcome... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to share variable with all controllers in laravel. I'd like to use [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers) to achieve this.

First create a `BlobServiceProvider` class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;

class BlobServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot() {}

    public function register() {

        $this->app->singleton('blobRestProxy', function() {
            $accountKey2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            $accountName1 = "xxxxxxxx";
            $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" . $accountName1 . ";AccountKey=" . $accountKey2;

            return ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
        });
    }
}
```

Then add the following line of code into `providers` array in `config\app.php` file.

```
App\Providers\BlobServiceProvider::class,
```

Now, you can use this variable `$blobRestProxy` in any controller like below.

```
$blobRestProxy = \App::make('blobRestProxy');
```